# How do you import two modules using the same name?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

Two modules:

```
#foo.py
def foo():
    print("foo")
```

and

```
#bar.py
def bar():
    print("bar")
```

I want to import both modules and put them together in the same namespace, like the following (which does not work):

```
import foo as a
import bar as a

a.foo()  # Error :(
a.bar()
```

How can you get it to work?

Comment: why can't you import foo as a and bar as b?

Comment: Because it would work nicer if both had the same name. For example: `import tkinter as tk` and `import bwidget as tk`

Comment: Why would it work nicer? What if both modules have a function with the same name?

Comment: You could do this with an intermediate module, which would `from foo import foo` and `from bar import bar`, then import and alias from that. This would give you a natural place to resolve any conflicts, too.

Comment: This is a terrible idea

Comment: Okay, I see now that this might not have been the best idea.

Comment: Why would you want something like that? This makes no sense.

Comment: Combining 2 (or more) arbitrary 3rd party modules into one namespace is a recipe for disaster, for the reasons that have already been mentioned. However, there _is_ a situation where this makes sense: when you've created a package that's composed of components defined in several source files, and you want to import all those components in one namespace. Of course, you still have to be careful that you don't accidentally create name collisions.

Answer (score 3):

You could create a new module containing both. Note, however, that any functions/classes/whatever that appears to have the same name in both module would only be defined to be the one from the last imported module:

**merger.py**

```
from foo import *
from bar import *
```

**your_code.py**

```
import merger as a

a.foo()
a.bar()
```

Not to mention the difficulty to trace where the `a.foobaz()` call was defined in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

```
import foo as a
import bar

# alias everything, you can use `bar.__all__` to automate this
a.bar = bar.bar

a.foo()
a.bar()
```

However, I would advise against doing this, as it will cause headaches for future maintainers of your code.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it was just an idea that I had and I thought it would make things easier.

Answer (score 1):

In first import, you assigned foo to "a" like a value.
In second import you override it with bar. That's why error.

Coming to your question - You cannot assign a single variable multiple values unless it is a dict, list, tuple or so on.

When you override a variable you assign it a new value instead of keeping both. That's what is happening to your imports.